# Command substitution: file or command not found

Tags: shell, shell-script, quoting, command-substitution

The following script

```
#!/bin/bash
QUERY='select * from cdr;'
MYROWS=$("sqlite3 -list -nullvalue NULL -separator ',' /var/log/asterisk/master.db '${QUERY}'")
```

gives me

```
./bla.sh: row 35: sqlite3 -list -nullvalue NULL -separator ',' /var/log/asterisk/master.db 'select * from cdr;': file or directory not found
```

If I execute directly

```
sqlite3 -list -nullvalue NULL -separator ',' /var/log/asterisk/master.db 'select * from cdr;'
```

then it works. I guess there is some error with the quotes that can't be seen on the error message. Please note that I need the single quotes around

```
select * from cdr;
```

Thanks for any hint on what I am doing wrong!

Comment: In the second line use double quotes only in the last part. Like: `MYROWS=$(sqlite3 ... "${QUERY}")`. You don't need single quotes because you have captured the special characters in the previous line.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I don't really understand way, because echo "${QUERY}" gives the query without the ' and ', so why does it work in the MYROWS line?

Comment: All you need is to pass the string `select * from cdr;` as a parameter to sqlite3. You need to use quotes (single or double) so the shell will pass it as one parameter, not because sqlite3 requires it. Because you need `${QUERY}` to be expanded, you have to use double quotes in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's inside `$(…)` is a shell command with the usual syntax. The double quotes around the whole snippet you intend as a command make it parsed as a single word, which is the first word of the command so it's interpreted as a command name.

Furthermore, your quoting of `$QUERY` isn't right: you need double quotes around it, so that the variable is expanded.

```
MYROWS=$(sqlite3 -list -nullvalue NULL -separator ',' /var/log/asterisk/master.db "${QUERY}")
```

Comment: I understand the first part of your reply, but not the one about explaing ${QUERY}, because when one simpley does echo ${QUERY}, therefore without any quotes, it is also expanded. I guess the shell is packaging the parameters into some kind of list and for the query to be one parameter, I need the quotes around it? But then, why do I need double quotes? Why not just single quotes? Thanks :-)

Comment: Found the difference between ' and " on http://www.linuxcommand.org/wss0060.php. Together with forcefsck's comment I now understand it completely :-)